# Build a project from sub-directory of Bitbucket repository in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Is it possible to build a project inside sub-directory of Bitbucket repository in Jenkins? I have been trying and testing Jenkins build from sub-directory of Bitbucket respository instead building everything from master branch because I do not want to put load on servers just for the testing purpose. I would like to know if it is possible and how it can be done. For instance, I would like to build only a project from sub directory 2 of Bitbucket repository as shown below. Please help with the diagram if possible. Thanks.

```
*/master
 - Directory 1
    - sub directory 1
          - pom.xml
        - **sub directory 2
               - pom.xml**

 - Directory 2
    - sub directory A
         -  subdirectory B
               - pom.xml
```

Comment: Just provide the pom.xml file path of the sub directory 2 (Ex: Directory 1/Sub Directory 1/Sub Directory 2/pom.xml)

Comment: Not sure how you do that inside Jenkins Build. I tried that already but did not get as expected. If possible could you post a screenshot? I replaced */master with Directory 1/Sub Directory 1/Sub Directory 2/pom.xml but still the build is executing from root branch building everything. I even tried  /master/Directory 1/Sub Directory 1/Sub Directory 2/pom.xml but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for an answer, you need to provide the path of pom.xml in the Root POM of Build section of Configure.

Go to Configure -> Scroll down to Build -> in Root POM enter subdirectory name/pom.xml

[[image reference][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWFEX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWFEX.png)

e.g. If your pom.xml is present at Repo/subdirectory/pom.xml you need to enter subdirectory/pom.xml in Root POM

Comment: Hi @Ninad Samant, I just saw your answer. AlthoughI resolved this issue long time ago, I agree with your answer.